# 'Mappings ConfigurationProperties' does not contain a definition for 'FluentMappings'

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am configuring my database using Fluent NHibernate. This is what I have in my `createSessionFactory` method.

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
        .ConnectionString(c => c
        .FromConnectionStringWithKey("connectionStringKey"))
        .Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
        .BuildSessionFactory());
}
```

I am getting an error under `fluentMappings`, it says:

> Mappings ConfigurationProperties does not contain a definition for FluentMappings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a parenthesis

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure()
        .Database(FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db.MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012
            .ConnectionString(c => c.FromConnectionStringWithKey("connectionStringKey")))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
        .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```